# Using the implicit function theorem to show a level surface is noncompact

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I was curious about finding conditions for a level surface to be compact and came up with this idea. In particular, let $F(x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}$ is nowhere vanishing on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. By the Implicit Function Theorem, the level surface $F = 0$ is then locally the graph of some continuously differentiable function $z = g(x,y)$ about any chosen point in the level surface. If the level surface is moreover the graph of some extension of $g$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then it cannot be compact, but I am not sure if the condition on $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}$ is enough to guarantee this. Does this argument lead anywhere?

One idea I had to find an extension of $g$ is to choose a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and "patch together" the functions given by the implicit function theorem to construct a function on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Your idea is right. All you have to do is argue that if you have $z=\phi_i(x,y)$ on $U_i$, then $\phi_i(x,y)=\phi_j(x,y)$ when $(x,y)\in U_i\cap U_j$. And, of course, you have to argue that you can choose these $U_i$ to cover $\Bbb R^2$. You're right that the last part is the subtle part: What happens to $\nabla F$ if there's a point with maximal $\|(x,y)\|$?

Comment: I think that $\nabla F$ would be parallel to the radial vector to the point, so the condition we need is that $F_ x=h(x,y,z) x,F_y=h(x,y,z)y,F_z=h(x,y,z) z$ never holds for some real valued function $h$, which implies that $F_x,F_y,F_z$ are nonvanishing? Thanks so much for taking the time to answer! :)

Comment: Not quite. I'm asking about a point on the level surface whose *projection* to the $xy$-plane has largest magnitude, not which is itself of largest magnitude. (BTW, give my regards to the MIT math department. I was an undergrad there 70-74 and taught there 79-81!!)

Comment: Oh that's amazing! I'll let them know, I'm sure they'll be happy to hear from you! :) Right now I'm taking 18.02a with Professor John Bush. I'm not really sure what can be said about the gradient in this case, other than that one of $F_x,F_y$ is nonzero.

Comment: Your instinct earlier was to think about Lagrange multipliers, no? Do that again. And then you should see what's going on geometrically. P.S. Check out my YouTube videos, linked in my profile, since you're interested in more theory than is in 18.02.

Comment: So if we apply Lagrange multipliers to maximize the square of distance $x^2 + y^2$ we get that $\nabla F$ is parallel to $<2x,2y,0>$, thus $F_z$ is $0$? So if we require that $F_z$ is nonzero, the only way for the level surface to be bounded is if $F_x = F_y = 0$ at some point?

Comment: No, you already arrived at your contradiction. So your level set must be non-compact; have you established that it must project onto the whole $xy$-plane?

Comment: I think that If the level surface didn't project onto the whole xy-plane, it would be a manifold with boundary, and hence would contain points at which a normal vector isn't defined, which contradicts the assumptions on $F$.

Comment: The level set is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^3$ and is a submsnifold. This we know. The projection map maps to an open subset of the plane. Have our earlier points shown that this set must have empty boundary?

Comment: Final hint: Non-compactness should be nailed down (although we haven't explicitly quite said why). Projecting to the entire plane just isn't necessarily true. Think about the $2$D example $F(x,y)=xy-1$.

Comment: That makes more sense, I couldn't really find any reason for why the image of the projection map has empty boundary. I'll think about this problem more. Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: You're welcome.Keep me posted! :)